# HTTPS не для всех сайтов

Tags: nginx

Как сделать, чтобы SSL соединение устанавливалось только в тех server блоках, где присутствует нижеприведенная строка?

```
listen      443 ssl default_server;
```

Допустим, есть сайт example.com и конфиг для него

```
server {
listen      80;
listen      443 ssl default_server;

server_name    example.com;

root        /home/web/example.com;

include acme;
include ssl_settings;

location / {
    index   index.html index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Соединение идёт и по httр://example.com и по httрs://example.com

В другом блоке есть сайт example2.com (для него сертификат я подключать не собираюсь).

Но при переходе по httрs://example2.com я получаю уведомление о том, что сертификат недействителен. 
Как сделать так, чтобы по https этот сайт вообще не грузился?

Comment: Во-первых, никак, во-вторых, лучше подключите-таки сертификат :)

Comment: @andreymal подключен в этой строке include ssl_settings; (конфиг находится с другом файле)

Comment: Ну вот и подключите его для example2.com

Comment: Хотел, чтобы example2.com был именно без сертификата. Ниже уже дали ответ, что так нельзя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. параметр `default_server` в директиве `listen` относится **ко всему** блоку `server`, и, для полноценного его функционирования, должен встречаться в конфигурации только один раз: *nginx* будет считать данный блок `server` дефолтным, т.е., если в http-запросе указан `host`, который не встречается ни в одном блоке `server`, то «сработает» именно тот блок, в котором встречается этот параметр.
2. для выбора нужного сертификата [*nginx* использует *sni*](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni) ([*server name indication*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)). при этом имя сервера передаётся клиентом (поддерживающим *sni*) **до** установления ssl-соединения. насколько мне известно, для того, чтобы общение с клиентом разрывалось **после** получения имени сервера, но **до** начала установки ssl-соединения, надо вносить изменения в используемую реализацию *openssl*.

   **вроде бы** подобное сделали у себя [*cloudflare*](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/09/in-depth-how-cloudflares-new-web-service-promises-security-without-the-key/). действительно ли это так, и публиковали ли они свои патчи, мне, увы, неизвестно (и вникать нет желания).

---

я бы порекомендовал вам всё-таки создать сертификат (благо, с помощью проекта [letsencrypt](/questions/tagged/letsencrypt) это сделать и просто и бесплатно), и, если не хотите использовать https для данного сайта, просто редиректить клиента на http.

Comment: с letsencrypt я как-раз сегодня ознакомился, именно его и подключил (конфиг сертификата подключил в этой строке include ssl_settings;)

Comment: я хотел, чтобы на одном сайте использовался https, а на другом - нет (и при попытке зайти по https я получал не "небезопасное соединение", а просто страницу о неудавшемся соединении). но, как я понял, так сделать нельзя исходя из вашего ответа и принципа работы Nginx.

Comment: да, «выдать страницу» можно уже лишь **после** установки соединения. а для установки соединения (ssl-соединения, по протоколу https) сервер должен предъявить клиенту сертификат. и если сертификат выпущен не для того домена, к которому обратился клиент, то клиент и напишет пользователю: «ой, сервер предъявил неправильный сертификат! давайте лучше уйдём с этого сайта, а?»

Comment: понял, спасибо.